# DataTables add id to cell in newly created row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've read up on using `fnCreatedRow` during the initialization phase of the table, but this solution will not work for me as I need to add the ID during the `table.row.add` phase because the ID I'm inserting is from the ajax success call that I make prior to adding the row.

Basically - When the user clicks my addRow button, I send a request off to my server and create the new row first in the database, and I return the unique lineID of that newly-created row.  I then want to use that `lineID` as the `id` element on the first cell of this table so that I can reference it later when the user saves the page.

Here is my function:

```
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {

  var q         = <?php echo json_encode($q); ?>;
  var d         = $('#d').html();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addRow.php',      
    data: { q:q, d:d },        
      success:function(data){          
        newRowId = data;
      }
  });

  lastRow++;  
  table.row.add([
    lastRow, /* add id = newRowID to this cell */
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""   
  ] ).draw( false );


});
```

## Update

I've found a way to add the ID, but I can only get it on the ROW itself, not inside a cell:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addRow.php',      
    data: { q:q, d:d },        
      success:function(data){          
        success       = JSON.parse(data);
        uCount        = success[0];
        uLineID       = success[1];

        lastRow++;            
        var newRow = table
            .row.add([
              lastRow,
              "",
              "",
              "",
              "",
              ""   
            ] )
            .draw( )
            .node( );

        $( newRow )
            .eq(0).attr( 'id', uLineID); /* I tried this */
            .attr('id', uLineID);        /* and this, separately */                                        
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the code below to set ID attribute for the first `td` element in the newly added row.

```
var newRow = table.row.add([
   lastRow,
   "",
   "",
   "",
   "",
   ""   
]).draw( false ).node();

$('td:eq(0)', newRow).attr('id', uLineID);
```

See [`row.add()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29) for more information.

Comment: to the rescue again!  This is the third question of mine that you've answered :)  Thank you so much.